# Adding build date/time to Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I'd like to be able to use **TIME** and **DATE** macros in Java, just as I would in C.  However, I'm aware they don't exist.  I've looked at various sites, and seen suggestions such as http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0532.html.  I understand that this could be implemented by creating a custom build.xml, but I'm reluctant to break that far from the Android tool chain.

An Eclipse Builder might have been a viable solution, but modifying files outside Eclipse seems like an unwise thing to do.

Has anyone a suggestion for accessing build date/time from within their Android application without a custom build.xml?  Is it possible to use the build.properties file, an Eclipse Builder, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a build.properties file written by ant script registered as a project builder. As part of ant builder configuration you can specify which resources to refresh post-build, so the fact that you are writing this file external to Eclipse isn't going to be much of an issue. Make sure to configure your source control system to ignore this build.properties file.